# Does getImage always return an Image object in imageJ

Tags: java, image-processing, imagej

I have created an ImagePlus object using the construstor,
 ImagePlus(java.lang.String pathOrURL)

```
imp=new ImagePlus(imgFile.getPath());
```

now I want to get the Image object(java.awt.Image) by calling getImage method.

```
img=imp.getImage();
jLabel2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(imgFile.getPath()));
jPanel3.validate();
```

but when i do that, i get nothing in return. Is it a must to use the constructor `(ImagePlus(java.lang.String title, java.awt.Image img))`, which will create a n *ImagePlus* object with an *Image* object, if i expect to use the *getImage()* method.

Comment: img is an Image object and imgFile is a File i read from the disk using openDialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean with you get nothing in return? Null, an Exception or an empty image?
Judging from the source file http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/source/ij/ImagePlus.java it should work.
I'd advise you to link the sources to your code, set a breakpoint at the imp= new ImagePlus(...) method, start the debugger and step into the call to see what's happening inside the imageJ call.

---